# Why does my JSP scriptlet fail to retrieve an int from the pageContext and cast it to a locally scoped primitive variable?

Tags: java, jsp, enums, scriptlet

I couldn't figure out a way to do this in EL/JSTL so when I do this:

```
<% 
int myIntPrimitiveValue = pageContext.getAttribute("myDataObject.myIntPrimitiveValue");
MyEnumObject myEnumInstance = myEnumObject.get(myIntPrimitiveValue);
String myEnumValueName = myEnumInstance.getName();
pageContext.setAttribute("myEnumValueName", myEnumValueName);
%>
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot cast from Object to int (line 1 in this snippet)
```

I know there's a valid value in `myDataObject.myIntPrimitiveValue` because I can print it like this with JSTL:

```
<c:out value="${myDataObject.myIntPrimitiveValue}"/>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because:

```
pageContext.getAttribute()
```

returns Object

What you need is converting the Object to int. For example:

```
int myIntPrimitiveValue = Integer.valueOf("" + pageContext.getAttribute("..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast object into your required type, as `pageContext.getAttribute()` return object such as `session` return object.
you need to do one of these

```
int myIntPrimitiveValue = (Integer)pageContext.getAttribute("myDataObject.myIntPrimitiveValue");

          or

int myIntPrimitiveValue = Integer.valueOf("" + pageContext.getAttribute("myDataObject.myIntPrimitiveValue"));
```